# How to display instance variables in HTML

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify

I receive a Shopify object that I want to display in Rails.

In my HTML I have this code:

```
<ul>
  <% @customers.each do |customer| %>
    <li><%= customer.orders %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I then get this output:

```
[#<ShopifyAPI::Order:0x007f90f53117c0 @attributes={"id"=>4889340686, "email"=>"", "closed_at"=>nil, "created_at"=>"2017-03-21T20:09:41-04:00", "updated_at"=>"2017-03-21T20:09:41-04:00", "number"=>3, "note"=>"", "token"=>"74b8cae748de2154dae08edc4cb9b0b8", "gateway"=>"manual", "test"=>false, "total_price"=>"121.00", "subtotal_price"=>"110.00", "total_weight"=>0, "total_tax"=>"11.00", "taxes_included"=>false, "currency"=>"AUD", "financial_status"=>"paid", "confirmed"=>true, "total_discounts"=>"0.00", "total_line_items_price"=>"110.00", "cart_token"=>nil, "buyer_accepts_marketing"=>false, "name"=>"#1003", "referring_site"=>nil, "landing_site"=>nil, "cancelled_at"=>nil, "cancel_reason"=>nil, "total_price_usd"=>"93.51", "checkout_token"=>nil, "reference"=>nil, "user_id"=>107636622, "location_id"=>40480334, "source_identifier"=>nil, "source_url"=>nil, "processed_at"=>"2017-03-21T20:09:41-04:00", "device_id"=>nil, "browser_ip"=>nil, "landing_site_ref"=>nil, "order_number"=>1003, "discount_codes"=>[], "note_attributes"=>[], "payment_gateway_names"=>["manual"], "processing_method"=>"manual", "checkout_id"=>nil, "source_name"=>"shopify_draft_order", "fulfillment_status"=>nil, "tax_lines"=>[#<ShopifyAPI::TaxLine:0x007f90f9e49ee0 @attributes={"title"=>"GST", "price"=>"11.00", "rate"=>0.1}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=true>], "tags"=>"", "contact_email"=>nil, "order_status_url"=>nil, "line_items"=>[#<ShopifyAPI::LineItem:0x007f90f9e492b0 @attributes={"id"=>9182800654, "variant_id"=>37496676110, "title"=>"Expensive Product", "quantity"=>1, "price"=>"100.00", "grams"=>0, "sku"=>"", "variant_title"=>nil, "vendor"=>"Gronade Dev Test", "fulfillment_service"=>"manual", "product_id"=>10105372366, "requires_shipping"=>true, "taxable"=>true, "gift_card"=>false, "name"=>"Expensive Product", "variant_inventory_management"=>nil, "properties"=>[], "product_exists"=>true, "fulfillable_quantity"=>1, "total_discount"=>"0.00", "fulfillment_status"=>nil, "tax_lines"=>[#<ShopifyAPI::TaxLine:0x007f90f3933650 @attributes={"title"=>"GST", "price"=>"10.00", "rate"=>0.1}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=true>]}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=true>, #<ShopifyAPI::LineItem:0x007f90f3932cf0 @attributes={"id"=>9182800718, "variant_id"=>37496692110, "title"=>"Cheap Product", "quantity"=>1, "price"=>"10.00", "grams"=>0, "sku"=>"", "variant_title"=>nil, "vendor"=>"Gronade Dev Test", "fulfillment_service"=>"manual", "product_id"=>10105380174, "requires_shipping"=>true, "taxable"=>true, "gift_card"=>false, "name"=>"Cheap Product", "variant_inventory_management"=>nil, "properties"=>[], "product_exists"=>true, "fulfillable_quantity"=>1, "total_discount"=>"0.00", "fulfillment_status"=>nil, "tax_lines"=>[#<ShopifyAPI::TaxLine:0x007f90f9e53be8 @attributes={"title"=>"GST", "price"=>"1.00", "rate"=>0.1}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=true>]}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=true>], "shipping_lines"=>[], "fulfillments"=>[], "refunds"=>[], "customer"=>#<ShopifyAPI::Customer:0x007f90f9e53238 @attributes={"id"=>5793410830, "email"=>nil, "accepts_marketing"=>false, "created_at"=>"2017-03-21T20:09:21-04:00", "updated_at"=>"2017-03-21T20:09:41-04:00", "first_name"=>"Benderditch", "last_name"=>"Cucumberpatch", "orders_count"=>1, "state"=>"disabled", "total_spent"=>"121.00", "last_order_id"=>4889340686, "note"=>nil, "verified_email"=>false, "multipass_identifier"=>nil, "tax_exempt"=>false, "phone"=>nil, "tags"=>"", "last_order_name"=>"#1003"}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=true>}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=true>]
```

How can I structure this output, or better how do I access these variables? I don't know what to do with the `@` annotated instance variables.

When I try to output the things like this:

```
<ul>
  <% @customers.each do |customer| %>
    <li><%= customer.orders.attributes %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I get an error.

Comment: `customer.orders` is an array, you must loop over it just like the `@customers` array

Comment: why do I get downvoted? thanks Iceman

Comment: Down votes and up votes are explained if you hover over the up/down arrows. Possibly it's because your question is answered in the documentation and tutorials and down votes are for questions not showing research. If you read the documentation and didn't find the answer, you should show where you searched and explain why those pages didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `customers.orders` is a dictionary of sorts (it's actually an `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`, you have to loop over it the same way that you looped over the `customers`. Like this:

```
<ul>
  <% @customers.each do |customer| %>
    <% customer.orders.each do |order| %>
      <li><%= order.whatever_field_you_want %></li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great! Would you mind accepting / up-voting my answer if it helped you :) Thanks!